# Docker Compose and Apache2: DocumentRoot '/app' is not a directory, or is not readable

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a simple HTML website using Apache2 and Docker. I have the following directory structure:

```
- web/
  - index.html
- docker-compose.yaml
- web.conf
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3"

services:
  apache2:
    image: webdevops/apache:latest
    container_name: water_net_flutter_app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '4100:80'
      - '4101:443'
    volumes:
      - ./web/:/var/www/html
      - ./data/log:/var/log/apache2
      - ./web.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    command: ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

**web.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ahmed.wagdy@apexnile.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I run `docker-compose up --build`, I encounter the following error:

```
water_net_flutter_app | AH00526: Syntax error on line 6 of /opt/docker/etc/httpd/conf.d/10-server.conf:
water_net_flutter_app | DocumentRoot '/app' is not a directory, or is not readable
water_net_flutter_app | Action '-D FOREGROUND' failed.
water_net_flutter_app | The Apache error log may have more information.
water_net_flutter_app exited with code 0
```

I can't figure out why Apache2 is looking for a DocumentRoot at '/app' instead of the specified './web/'. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Why are you using the `webdevops/apache` image rather than the [official httpd image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd)? If you're going to use `webdevops/apache`, you'll need to read [the documentation](https://dockerfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/DockerImages/dockerfiles/apache.html) to understand how to configure it.